# What is deemed constant?

Tags: type-conversion, constants

What is the meaning of deemed constant?

I've searched for it in google but its not mentioned anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure they are not trying to say the variable has been assigned as a constant?

Comment: A little more context would probably help...

Answer (score 0):

To deem something is to believe it to be so.  So if something is deemed to be constant, then we have reason to believe that it is constant -- perhaps empirical evidence.  But there is the possibility that we are wrong.

A physicist would prefer a theoretical explanation of why a particular property is constant, rather than just relying on observations.

In programming, there is no such uncertainty.  We depend on our language compiler and run-time to ensure that a constant is just that.